# @Transient vs decorator

Tags: hibernate, jpa, design-patterns

I am bit conflicted in modelling my entities.

We have an entity with around 6-8 instance variables. Two of them are not actually persisted in database, but only used for doing some validation or to display in UI. So when we fetch entity, we populate with some external lookup.

Now, according to one of my colleague its better practice use decorator instead of using @Transient. To a certain extent I agree. Because it clarifies actual model which DB represents.

But it will add additional boilerplate for some cases (e.g. for business I can name entity as MyEntityBO. But if I use it for UI...again name will be bit confusing.

My question is, what scenario its better to use @Transient rather then a decorator or vice-versa

Comment: Neither. You shouldn't use entities directly from the UI for that very reason. You should rather have a view-specific model that is a representation of the model specifically designed for the view. That view-model belongs to the UI. The view-model may encapsulate the original model through composition, but that wouldn't be a decorator per se. That is unless your application is simple CRUD, in that case just go with @Transient.

Comment: can you show sample code to give an idea how you'll add decorator pattern here?

Comment: @plalx In my case, its not always UI. and object is used for other validation too. composition seems better way to handle this situation. Create 2 object. ObjectUI, ObjectBO. so only getter with what is needed for UI wil be there. so accidentally, something that should not be visible to UI but should be there in main entity e.g. id / password can be hidden. (again, counter argument here is "@IgnoreJson" :) I am trying to understand in what cases "@Transient" is still viable. If like you said application is only CRUD, it makes more sense to have just "@Transient"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a good practice to use entity for both: DB mapping and UI mapping. Always think about Single Responsibility Principle. Entity should be just responsible for DB mapping, no more. You should create DTO layer for UI representation. But in this case you should create converters as well, it's boring, I propose to use Mapstruct - http://mapstruct.org.
If you have to use @Transient this is the first sign that smth goes wrong, keep in mind it. Good luck :)

```
@Entity
public class User {
   @Id
   Long id;
   String name;
}

public class UserDto{
   Long id;
   String name;
}

public class UserConverter{
   public UserDto toDto(User user) {
      if (user == null) return null;
      UserDto dto = new UserDto();
      dto.setId(user.getId());
      dto.setName(user.getName());
      return dto;
   }

   public User toEntity(UserDto dto){...}  
}
```

And in DTO object you can create additional fields or methods you need for some purpose

Comment: issue is maintaining this DTO. Its creates unnecessary verbose code. But if I make it composition, it makes it more maintainable. My doubt was about "@Transient" that why they created one if entity was just supposed to map DB structure ? whats motivation for it. where its more viable to use this....But I do understand now...single responsibility principle.

Comment: I don't recommend to use wrapper for that, you should segregate your dao layer, service layer and UI layer. Ideally you should get object from db, do business logic, construct object that you need on UI side and send it. If you send wrapper it means that entity is inside wrapper object, this is wrong, cause you send your domain object to UI. And it can lead to LazyInitException as well, cause your detached entity has been sent to UI. You should send fully constructed DTO object to UI. Actually DTO pattern is one of the best way how to handle LazyInitException.

Comment: Think about your architecture, your layers should be lousily coupled and work with their own data. It will be perfect if your DTO does not have any methods, it's just a dumb data. UI is responsible for handling that data

Answer (score -1):

Main disadvantage of using Decorator Pattern is that the code maintenance can be a problem(from my experience). 
I strongly suggest you to go with @Transient.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit about "code maintenance" ? what issues or indecent you saw where it created issue ?

Comment: In our project Decarator pattern had many similer kind of objects.Thus during maintenance it becomes an headache.Also in case you plan to migrate (in future) it is inconvenient than transient pattern.But also if you have small no of objects it will not be an issue.I myself faced issues so suggesting.Cheers